# How to pass "char* a" to "const char*"?

Tags: c++

Could you tell me the way to pass the value (char * a) to the value (const char* b)?

For example,

```
char * str = "Tokyo";
const char *;

"char = str"  is OK?
```

Comment: Where is your code in all these questions? Post the code to show us what you are trying to do.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  For example the C++ has `const_cast<>` and the C language doesn't.

Comment: Also `char * str = "Tokyo";` is deprecated in C++ and a good compiler with warnings turned on should at least tell you that.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Pick one!

Comment: Sorry this is C++.

Comment: A character literal, such as `"Tokyo"`, is constant, so you should declare a pointer to constant data:  `char const * str = "Tokyo";` or my favorite: `const char tokyo[] = "Tokyo";`.

Comment: You just pass is, conversion is implicit: `char str[] = "Tokyo"; const char* psz = str;`

Answer (score 7):

```
char * str = "Tokyo";
```

In c++, this is **not** allowed <sup>†</sup>. You may not assign a const array (such as a string literal) to a non-const pointer.

```
const char *;
```

This is not allowed, because a variable declaration must have a name (unless it's a function argument).

```
const char *str = non_const_pointer_or_array;
```

The above is OK in c++.

† Implicit conversion from const to non-const is allowed in c but typically discouraged by compiler warnings. It was deprecated in c++ and not allowed at all since c++11.

Answer (score 5):

In c++, it should just work. Native/Builtin types are automatically convertible to more const, but not to less const.

Therefore:

```
void foo(const char*) {
}

int main() {
    char s[] = {'x', 'y', 'z', '\0'};
    foo(s); //Compiles fine.
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine, however the other way around, one has to use a const_cast. One should however not lie to the compiler and indicate that something is non const, while in actual fact it is const, as the program behavior in that case is undefined (one cannot know what the behavior of the program might be). const_cast is typically only used when old APIs require char* arguments despite it not modifying the arguments, and should never be used to "lie" to the compiler.

Example:

```
void some_old_api(char*){}

int main() {
    const char* cs = "xyz";
    some_old_api(const_cast<char*>(cs));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And one **can't** use const_cast, at the peril of invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, I'll add this, and that const_cast is typically for the sake of compatiblity with old apis.

Comment: Re you added code edit: You have UB in the code since `cs` is `const`.  A correct example would be to have a non-const array, pass it to a function taking a `const char *` and then `const_cast` away the const to pass it to a function that takes a `char *`.

Comment: @NathanOliver. It depends whether some_old_api modifies cs. If it doesn't and one knows it, then this does not invoke UB. I'll check this, but as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Nope.  In your example you cast away the `const` on `cs` with `some_old_api(const_cast<char*>(cs);`.  Since `cs` is `const` you now have UB.

Comment: Yes, I do cast it way merely for the legacy call to compile, but it is still const, as the legacy call does not modify it... Therefore not UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver Nope, casting const to non-const does *not* result in UB. Only if  `some_old_api` modifies the pointed object does any UB happen. If `some_old_api` is guaranteed not to modify, this is OK and quite typical when interacting with a C API.

Comment: @user2079303 and Werner.  You are correct.  I considered the cast a modification but it is not.  As long as it is never modified it is okay.

Answer (score -3):

A character array hard-coded in your program *is* a `const char*`, so you can declare it as `const char* str = "Tokyo";`
Or, when you do have a `char* str`, you can cast it as follows: `const char* myconst = (const char*) str;`

Comment: Wrong. a string literal is **not** of type `const char*`

Comment: About C: While a _string literal_ **behaves** as if it was `const` qualified (and should be treated the alike). it actually is not! The standard is very clear about this. It also mentions writing to a string literal is a comon extension of the standard. Furthermore, if it was, you could not use `char *str = "It works";`.

Comment: `"Tokyo"` has the type of `const char[N]` where `N` is the number of characters plus a null terminator.

Comment: @Olaf I do get compiler warnings from Xcode 7.3 if I try `char* str = "It works";` It will compile, but it complains loudly.

Comment: @NathanOliver OK, good point. I'll consider myself corrected on that point. But that doesn't make `const char* str = "Tokyo";` invalid.

Comment: @Logicrat Never said it did.  It is a totally correct way to store a string literal.  My only issue is with you saying a string literal is a `const char *` since it is not.

Comment: @Logicrat: Use a C compiler. I was very clear in my comment. Note that it is also not a `char *`, but a `char []` as NathanOliver pointed out. As every array, it decasy to a pointer to the first element for most usages.